# devise create error message for duplicate username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using rails 5.2 with devise. I have added a unique username field in my database for devise users. 
I'm getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error for my database when trying to signup with a duplicate username. I want to have an error message just like devise has default for emails. Thanks!

edit full error message:

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint  "index_users_on_username" DETAIL: Key
>   (username)=(supertest) already  exists. : INSERT INTO "users"
>   ("email", "encrypted_password",  "created_at", "updated_at",
>   "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)  RETURNING "id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [add a validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :confirmable, :recoverable, :validatable # ...
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
end
```

The validation prevents the low level `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception since Rails will not attempt to write to the db if the validation fails.